# Move list box items from one listbox to another listbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to move  listbox items between two listboxes.Before that i created two arrraylists  for each listbox.so before moving the listbox item i am trying to add the items to the arraylist. here is the code

```
 foreach (string st in listbox1.Items)
            {
                arraylist1.Add(st1);
            }
```

but i am getting an exeption Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to type 'System.String'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach (string st in listbox1.Items)` should be

```
 foreach (ListItem st in listbox1.Items) 
           // your code
```

Answer (score 5):

You're getting this error because `listbox1.Items` is a ListItemCollection.

```
foreach (ListItem li in listbox1.Items)
{
    arraylist1.Add(li.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
foreach (ListItem li in listbox1.Items) 
{     
     arraylist1.Add(li.Text); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ListBox.Items is of ListItemCollection type. It consists of ListItem objects, not strings.

What You are trying to do is:

```
        foreach (ListItem lstItem in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            arraylist1.Add(lstItem);
        }
```

Comment: I actually don't think that's what OP was trying to do.

Comment: @JamesJohnson You are right, I've edited the post, thank You! Yet, it stays unclear whether OP have arraylist of ListItems or Texts. If it is texts, then your answer is correct, otherwise it's mine.

Answer (score 1):

This is because a list item is an object in it's own right and not a string object. So change the string to ListItem in your code above and it should work fine.